# how to associate a new user's email internet domain with a network on my website? (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, if a user signs up using email johndoe@xyz.com, I want this user to be part of the "XYZ" network on my website. People will be only allowed to join their respective networks. There will be numerous networks on my website and they are all separate from each other. This is how the user table looks in schema.db

```
create_table "activities", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  end

  add_index "activities", ["owner_id", "owner_type"], :name => "index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type"
  add_index "activities", ["recipient_id", "recipient_type"], :name => "index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type"
  add_index "activities", ["trackable_id", "trackable_type"], :name => "index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type"



  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
    t.boolean   "admin",           :default => false
  end
```

I'm using activities to track the user model and I display them in a "feed". I would like to add something like this in view: "Username has joined the XYZ network." by tracking the user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Network` model. It's database table will contain a string called `domain`. A network will have many users; a user will belong to a network. Add a `network_id` string to the user model as well.

Associations and support methods should look like this:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  def peers
    self.users
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
  delegate :peers => :network

  validates :network_id, :presence => true
  # ...
end
```

Now this is possible:

```
@network.users
# => collection of all users in a network

@user.network
# => the network user belongs to

@user.peers
# => collection of all users within @user's network
# => note: this will include @user itself in the collection
```

When a user signs up, create or find a `Network` record containing the domain string extracted from the user's email address. When a user updates their email address, check if the domain has changed, and re-create or re-find a `Network` record with matching domain.

It is tempting to automate this in the model, but is properly implemented in the controller, specifically `UsersController#create` and `UsersController#update`.

```
def create
  # ...isntantiate @user...
  #
  set_network_id_from_email(@user.email)
  #
  # ...save...
end

def update
  # ...instantiate @user...
  #
  if @user.email != params[:user][:email]  
    set_network_id_from_email(params[:user][:email])
  end
  #
  # ...update_attributes...
end

private

def set_network_id_from_email(addr)
  if email = Mail::Address.new(addr)
    @user.network_id = Network.find_or_create_by_domain(email.domain)
  end
end
```